# Reverse engineer a POSTed object into a c# class

Tags: c#, javascript, builder

Does Visual Studio have a means to examine a POSTed object and generate a c# class for it, sorta like it does for a wsdl document, or how you can create an xsd from an xml document?  How would I do that?  If not, is there a tool/ plugin that performs this sort of thing?

I tried to give an example of what I was getting before, and people got hung up on the text of the POST message, rather than the shape I was highlighting.  So no text now, just the question.

It seems like it would be much easier to build a template POCO class from a POST operation when you have a fairly complex javascript-based object you are sending back to the server.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about [json](http://json2csharp.com/)?

Comment: Well, the object was originally json in the DOM, but I don't think it gets POSTed as such.  It ends up a long list of variables that go as (I assume) form-encoded data to the server.  I want a way to listen on the server side and create a POCO class from what I get -- or intercept it and create the class.  It doesn't necessarily have to be in VS.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Maybe you can use http://json2csharp.com/ BTW: when working with web applications [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) can help you also. (Note: Still a bad question as previous one)

Comment: Hmm.  the json2Csharp thing works pretty well.  Not exactly what I was looking for, but it gets the job done.  You're wrong about my assumption being wrong, it certainly is not being posted as json.  It is form-encoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess a little bit here as there is no example code to base this on. It sounds like you want to take some unknown (at compile time) list of variables and instantiate them into a class on the C# end. As far as I understand it you are posting a JSON object from the client back to the server and want it to be bound to an equivalent POCO object. Yes?

If so, you would probably be looking at reflection and/or anonymous types. Personally I don't see the point, as you won't be able to strongly-type anything to it on the server, so it may as well be a `Dictionary<string, string>` of properties in the end. You could write a generic method to check each property and see what types it can be converted into (using `Convert.ChangeType`) but that sounds like a lot of work.

Drop in some more info and I'll try and give a better answer.

Comment: People seem get upset and confused when I give more info.  I was able to create the classes by intercepting the object before it was converted into form-encoded data and stringifying it, then dropping it into the json2csharp.com web application.  Kudos to @EZI, but I'll give you the rep for actually trying.

Comment: Understood, and appreciated. For what it's worth, people mostly seem to get on their soapbox if they perceive that what you are trying to do works around (rather than within) the framework you are using. So it may not be a matter of people not wanting to help, but more of a case 'is there a better way to do this'? Just a thought.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to communicate my ambivalence to the tool being used, but you'll always have people convinced you're an idiot.  It doesn't bother me, really, but I'm certainly not going to reward such behavior.  :)  have a good night.